# entity framework transactions and sql azure default isolation level

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database, transactionscope, isolation-level

According to this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx

```
SQL Azure default database wide setting is to enable read committed 
snapshot isolation (RCSI)
```

Am I right in assuming that:

A)  The following code defaults to Serializable (overriding the database default)

```
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {                                                               

        }
```

B)  The following code it defaults to ReadCommitted with Snapshot Isolation (and not just plain ReadCommitted)

```
        TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
        options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;

        using (TransactionScope transaction = new 
          TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
        {                                                               

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Yes. By default the isolation level will be Serializable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx

b) For that transaction the isolationlevel will be just ReadCommitted. For Snapshot you would need

```
  options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx

Comment: So I would need use transactionscope with Snapshot to enable Read committed snapshot on SQL Azure. Also, will any selects that are outside the transactionscope - example a simple select  objectcontext.employees.Select(e => e.FirstName) - will be the default database isolation level which in SQL Azure is read committed snapshot?

Comment: Sure, when you execute a select outside that transaction, it will default again to read committed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i think your isolation level will be only SnapShot not the read committed snapshot which are two different isolations

It differs from the SNAPSHOT isolation level in that instead of providing a reader
with the last committed version of the row that was available when the transaction started, a reader gets the last committed version of the row that was available when the statement started